# pythonic way to drop columns where length of list in column is x

Tags: python, pandas

I would like drop the rows where a certain column has a list of length X. What is the most pythonic or efficient way? Instead of looping...

Code example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'column_1': ['1', '2', '3'] ,
    'column_2': [['A','B'], ['A','B','C'], ['A']], 
    "column_3": ['a', 'b', 'c']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

drop rows where length of list = 3. In this case, row 2 should be deleted since the length of the list is 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) to make a boolean indexing

```
new_df = df[df["column_2"].str.len().ne(3)]


  column_1 column_2 column_3
0        1   [A, B]        a
2        3      [A]        c
```

Or if you want to remove rows where list length is equal or greater than 3:

```
new_df = df[df["column_2"].str.len().le(2)]
```

---

```
print(df["column_2"].str.len().ne(3))
#0     True
#1    False
#2     True
#Name: column_2, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Probably .ne(3) is what OP is looking for.

Comment: Oh thanks! I'm going to take a look to the difference of .ne and .le

Comment: Nothing:) @ToninoFernandez

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

```
res = df[df["column_2"].apply(len).le(2)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  column_1 column_2 column_3
0        1   [A, B]        a
2        3      [A]        c
```